# Como leer datos de una api en laravel 10

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Estoy tratando de leer una respuesta de una api tipo post de laravel pero cuando trato de acceder a un valor del api, me sale el siguiente error Undefined array key "id"

$client = new Client();

```
    $body = [
        //Aca tengo todo mi body del api
    ];
    $headers = [
        //Aca tengo todo el header correspondiente al api
    ];
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'link Api', [
        'json' => $body, 
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);

    $responseBody = $response->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($responseBody,true);
    echo $data['id'];
```

Tambien he tratado con un foreach pero sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para la gente que pueda tener el mismo problema la solución es:

```
    $data = $response->getBody();

    $data = json_decode($data);

    $data->message->qr_link;
```

En mi caso message es el que tenia todo el acceso a los datos